# How can I add a straight line on my chart on the basis of user input from drop down menu in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, charts

I have generated a chart in asp.net c#, which gets user data from the database and display it. Now I want to add a line to it which can indicate the baseline set by the user. I think it might be a new series which will be drawn from start to end. It will be ideal if the user is able to change it and on changing the line is redrawn. I have dates on x-axis and activity time on y axis. In the following picture I want line like Goal. Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: Are you using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting

Comment: I believe yes. System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways I know which can be used to achieve this line.
One is by adding the  tag but the line will appear under the bars. 
If you want the line to appear above the bars then you need to add another series of type line chart. Make its x axis secondary and specify the values so that it appears as a straight line. Hide the lengends and labels etc for line chart.